# Pyarrow Error when Querying from Big Query

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, pyarrow

When running the code below, I am receiving a **pyarrow** error. I have installed **pyarrow** and I am still getting the same error. I am able to access the table and see the schemas, etc. but **to_dataframe()** does not work when copying the same code as Google Bigquery documentation.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

key_path = key_path #personal json file
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_path, scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
)
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=credentials.project_id,)
query = """
    select * 
    from `table` 
    limit 10;
"""
df = client.query(query).to_dataframe()  # I have also tried with df = client.query(query).result().to_dataframe()
```

I am receiving the following error when running:

```
ValueError: The pyarrow library is not installed, please install pyarrow to use the to_arrow() function.
```

Comment: What happens if you run `import pyarrow` in a python shell?

Comment: No issue with the import. Same error message as before for the query.

Comment: I tried your code in my environment. Can you try "pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery[pandas]"? This installation added some libraries that might have been missed. And also check if the versions are compatible. In my environment, library versions are like this: **google-cloud-bigquery**, Version: 2.16.0 and **pyarrow**, Version: 3.0.0 . I'm suggesting this because I wasn't able to recreate the issue as your code worked perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
`import pandas as pd`
`query_string = """ SELECT * FROM Table limit 10;  """`  
`df = pd.read_gbq(query_string,project_id,dialect='standard')`

Comment: This is a different library that I am not able to use due to its requiring of authorization and it's not a google-bigquery library.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed this same issue, I also tried below, which did not work.

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery[pandas]
```

in the end I just **removed all the packages** in my virtualenv (actually I just deleted the env folder) **then reinstalled them** (actually I just made a new virtualenv and installed the packages I needed)

after installing

```
pip install google-cloud-bigquery
```

the only extra thing I needed to do was.

```
pip install google-cloud-bigquery[pandas]
```

im sure you could just remove google-cloud-biguqery and its dependencies, as a more elegant solution to just straight up deleting the virtualenv and remaking it.