# Error when transforming resultos to df from Bigquery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

This is the typical connection I have from my local device:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials_path = "credential path"
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(credentials_path) 
project_id = "project id"
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project_id)
sql_query ="SELECT * FROM table"
query_job = client.query(sql_query)
results = query_job.result()
```

Until there everything runs nice, but here:

```
df = results.to_dataframe()
```

I get this error:

[image]

And I haven't been able to solve it. I have found some questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67427903/pyarrow-error-when-querying-from-big-query),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65275911/import-pyarrow-not-working-error-is-valueerror-the-pyarrow-library-is-not-i)) that are pretty similar but don't have an accepted answer. In my problem, I have that package installed, so it seems that google cloud is not able to import that package?  Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried `pip install db_dtypes`?

Comment: Has your issue been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Use `google-cloud-bigquery[pandas]` as requirement instead of `google-cloud-bigquery`.

For installing it: `pip install google-cloud-bigquery[pandas]`